# Is if statement in for loop faster than one by one if statements in Java?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, if-statement, hashmap

I wonder that if I use a HashMap to collect the conditions and loop each one in one if statement can I reach higher performance rather than to write one by one if - else if statement?

In my opinion, one-by-one if-else, if statements may be faster because in for loop runs one more condition in each loop like, does the counter reach the target number? So actually each if statement, it runs 2 if statements. Of course inside of the statements different but if we talk about just statement performance, I think one-by-one type would be better?

Edit: this is just a sample code, my question is about the performance differences between the usage of these statements.

```java
Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>
String letter ="d";
int n = 4;
words.put("a",1);
words.put("b",2);
words.put("c",3);
words.put("d",4);
words.put("e",5);

words.forEach((word,number)->{
if(letter.equals(word){
System.out.println(number*n);
});
```

```java
String letter ="d";
int n = 4;
if(letter.equals("a"){
System.out.println(number*1);
}else if(letter.equals("b"){
System.out.println(number*2);
}else if(letter.equals("c"){
System.out.println(number*3);
}else if(letter.equals("d"){
System.out.println(number*4);
}else if(letter.equals("e"){
System.out.println(number*5);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show your code to better explain what you mean. Are you using short-circuits in any of your conditions or breaking when a condition is met?

Comment: I'll write an example code.

Comment: Why don't you test it it can be can easily tested it. Do both, make some huge loops and test the performance. You can then edit your question if your findings and ask why that behavior happened. :)

Comment: You are most likely wasting your time on pointless micro optimization. Java speed comes from the jit translating byte code into machine code. What you do in Java source on this level has close to zero influence. Write simple easy to read and understand code. And hint: the jit is really good at translating simple code into fast machine instructions.

Comment: @GhostCat micro optimization is *usually* pointless, but not always. It shouldn't be taken as an article of faith that anybody looking to micro optimize be automatically discouraged from doing so. And while it's true that the compiler can make incredible optimizations, it will most definitely make *different* optimizations based on what code your write in many circumstances. So what code you write very much does matter.

Comment: Why loop at all in the first case: just use `words.get(letter)`, and do stuff if it is not null. And in the second case, use a switch.

Comment: OP "in my opinion" your (and my) opinion isn't worth the paper it's written on. Measure.

Comment: @mypetlion therefore I said "most likely". And as expected, the OP shows code that contains print statements. That tells us that he doesn't have a real performance problem but an imaginary one. It wouldn't even make sense to measure the code presented here.

Comment: @AndyTurner this code is just a visualization of my performance question. you can put the value in the condition instead of a key.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, having a HashMap but then doing an iterative lookup seems to be a bad idea.  The point of using a HashMap is to be able to do a hash based lookup.  That is much faster than doing an iterative lookup.

Also, from your example, cascading if-then tests will definitely be faster, since they will avoid the overhead of the map iterator and extra function calls.  Also, they will avoid the overhead of the map iterator skipping empty storage locations in the hash map backing array.  A better question is whether the cascading if-thens are faster than iterating across a simple list.  That is hard to answer.  Cascading if-thens seem likely to be faster, except that if there are a lot of if-thens, then a cost of loading the code should be added.

For string lookups, a list data structure provides adequate behavior up to a limiting value, above which a more sophisticated data structure must be used.  What is the limiting value depends on the environment.  For string comparisons, I've found the transition between 20 and 100 elements.

For particular lookups, and whether low level optimizations are available, the transition value may be much larger.  For example, doing integer lookups using "C", which will can do direct memory lookups, the transition value is much higher.

Typical data structures are HashMaps, Tries, and sorted arrays.  Each fits particular patterns of access.  For example, sorted arrays are fastest and most compact, but are expensive to update.  HashMaps support dynamic updates, and for good hash functions, provide constant time lookups.  But, HashMaps are space inefficient, since they depend on having empty cells between hash values.

For cases which do not involve "very large" data sets, and which are not in critical "hot" code paths, HashMaps are the usual structure which is used.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I definitely agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Map and you want to retrieve one letter, I'm not sure why you would loop at all?

```
Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>
String letter ="d";
int n = 4;
words.put("a",1);
words.put("b",2);
words.put("c",3);
words.put("d",4);
words.put("e",5);

if (words.containsKey(letter) {
  System.out.println(words.get(letter)*n);
}
else
{
  System.out.println(letter + " doesn't exist in Map");
}
```

If you aren't using the benefits of a Map, then why use a Map at all?

A forEach will actually touch every key in the list. The number of checks on your if/else is dependent on where it is in the list and how long the list of available letters is. If the letter you choose is the last one in the list then it would complete all checks before printing. If it is first then it will only do one which is much faster than having to check all.

It would be easy for you to write the two examples and run a timer to determine which is actually faster. 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-measure-elapsed-time

There are a lot of wasted calculations if you have to run through 1 million if/else statements and only select one which could be anywhere in the list. This doesn't include typos and the horror of code maintenance. Using a Map with an index would be much quicker. If you are only talking about 100 if/else statements (still too many in my opinion) then you may be able to break even on speed.

Comment: don't access the map twice: `Integer result = words.get(letter); if (result!=null) { System.out.println(result*n); } .....`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Valid point. I shouldn't have accessed it in the check containsKey() anyway.

Comment: I just gave this code as an example. I am talking about the statements vs loop performance. You might not know the received data and you might have different conditions in loop.

Comment: You should post the code you would use if you are asking for help. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good site for reviewing code and performance. If you use HashMap not as intended and If/Else correctly then I would imagine you could make it have higher or lower performance. A question that might be beneficial is `Why am I typing the same thing over and over again?`.